# Knowing the key, how do I decrypt the affine cipher?

Tags: encryption, classical-cipher, affine-cipher

I have an encryption function

$$E(p) = (ap + b) \mod{26}$$

where the parameters are  $a=7$, $b = 10$, and $p$ is the plaintext letter.

I was asked to decrypt the ciphertext

```
LJMKGM
```

using this information.

So, I tried to solve in this way:

1. I wrote the letters and indexed them from 0 to 25.
2. For each indexed ciphertext letter, I used this function to decrypt $$D(c) = (ac-b) \mod{26}$$ where $c$ is the number that represents the ciphertext letter.

I know that the plaintext is "please". For the first ciphertext letter, my method works, but for the rest it doesn't work.. what is my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a special case of the [affine cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher) where $m=26$.

Let's encrypt a single letter using your $E$. Let it be `m`, say, which is at index 12. So, $$E(12) = (7 \cdot 12 + 10) \mod{26} = 16$$

Now if we try to use the $D$ in your question, we decrypt this as:

$$D(16) = (7 \cdot 16 - 10) \mod{26} = 24$$

which is obviously not right. The issue is that your $E$ and $D$ aren't really inverses. The general technique in math classes for finding simple function inverses is to swap the dependent/independent variables and solve, so let's do that to find the inverse for $E$.

Let $y = E(p)$ for convenience's sake. Now let's swap $y$ and $p$ in the encryption function (and swap over to modular arithmetic notation):

$$p \equiv ay+b \mod{26}$$

and try to solve for $y$ (aka $E(p)$). Well, we move $b$ over first, which is just your typical "Algebra" material from school.

$$p - b \equiv ay \mod{26}$$

Now here comes the kicker: you need to "divide by" $a$. Now, I don't know your abstract algebra background, but arithmetic modulo $n$ takes place in the [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, also sometimes written as $\mathbb{Z}_n$. The issue is that multiplicative inverses are not guaranteed to exist in rings. In the case of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, an element $x$ only has a multiplicative inverse if $\gcd(x, n)=1$. Fortunately for us, $a = 7$ and $m = 26$ are coprime, so $a^{-1}$ does exist.

Hence, we can write:

$$a^{-1}(p - b) \equiv y \mod{26}$$

which gives us:

$$D(c) = a^{-1}(c - b) \mod{26}.$$

This agrees with Wikipedia's article on the affine cipher, so it's good to know that we're not totally off-track here. How do you find $a^{-1}$? The article [Modular Multiplicative Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) on Wikipedia gives you a few ways. In this case, I'd probably just try trial-and-error, but you can also use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to do so if you dislike trial and error. Fortunately for us, someone at Princeton is hosting this [modular inverse calculator](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dsri/modular-inversion.html), which tells us that $a^{-1} = 15$.

So, taking the above $E(12) = 16$, let's see if our new $D$ works:

$$D(16) = 15 \cdot (16 - 10) \mod{26} = 12$$

which succeeds! From there, I trust you can complete the computation for your ciphertext.

Comment: thanks a lot! this was good explanation! 
so all I need is to find the inverse function for decryption and the inverse number of the given 'a' in mod26.